# Como calcular o tempo de uma consulta LINQ?

Tags: c#

Tenho uma tabela com +- 900mil registros. Faço algumas consultas usando cláusulas `where` e quero ver a diferença de tempo entre elas.

Como faço pra mostrar o tempo em um `label` ao final da consulta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Você pode usar o MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/):

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;

var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
using (profiler.Step("Minha query"))
{
    var alguma coisa = /* Coloque sua consulta LINQ aqui */
}
```

O MiniProfiler trabalha com vários *templates*. Só escolher o que faz parte da sua aplicação e usar.

Comment: Pra quem usa Visual Studio, já tem próprio `Analyze Performance`.

Comment: O MiniProfiler pode ser usado em qualquer tipo de aplicação. Basta verificar o link que coloquei e verificar se há algum tipo de configuração específica. A pergunta explicita que o resultado deve sair numa *label*, portanto, não é usando a funcionalidade do Visual Studio.

Comment: o que quer dizer a linha `using (profiler.Step("Minha query"))` já que a consulta vai estar embaixo?

Comment: Ela marca tudo o que está dentro do bloco como "Minha query". O que o MiniProfiler devolve pra você é o tempo total de tudo o que foi colocando dentro desse bloco.